# Confused by vault secrets and group_vars variables

Tags: ansible

I have this playbook to demo my problem:

```yaml
---
- name: Debug var
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Replace dots with underscores in web_domain
      set_fact:
        cert_data_var_1: "vault_{{ web_domain.replace('.', '_') }}_cert_data"

    - name: Replace dots with underscores in web_domain
      set_fact:
        cert_data_var_2: "{{ web_domain.replace('.', '_') }}_cert_data"

    - name: Create Cert File /tmp/certfile.pem
      copy:
        content: |
          some secret is {{ some_secret }}
          cert data 1      = {{ cert_data_var_1 }}
          vars cert data 1 = {{ vars[cert_data_var_1] }}
          cert data 2      = {{ cert_data_var_2 }}
          vars cert data 2 = {{ vars[cert_data_var_2] }}
        dest: /tmp/certfile.pem
```

`web_domain` is defined in the inventory.

The values come from the files:

`playbooks/group_vars/all/global_vars.yml`:

```yaml
some_secret: "{{ vault_some_secret }}"
example_com_cert_data: "{{ vault_example_com_cert_data }}"
```

and `playbooks/group_vars/all/global_vault.yml`, which is vault encrypted and displayed here with the help of `ansible-vault view playbooks/group_vars/all/global_vault.yml`:

```yaml
vault_some_secret: secret-code
vault_example_com_cert_data: |
  this is the secret data
  one
  two
  three
```

I run the playbook like so:

```bash
ansible-playbook -i myinventory playbooks/debug_var.yml
```

Then I cat the `/tmp/certfile.pem` and it has this data in it:

```
some secret is secret-code
cert data 1      = vault_example_com_cert_data
vars cert data 1 = this is the secret data
one
tow
three

cert data 2      = cert_data_var_2
cert data 2      = example_com_cert_data
vars cert data 2 = {{ vault_example_com_cert_data }}
```

What I do not understand is how come I get the line:

```
some secret is secret-code
```

which is what I would expect and then I also get the line:

```
cert data 2      = example_com_cert_data
```

I had expected to get this:

```
vars cert data 2 = this is the secret dert data
one
two
three
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: You are hitting [this](https://witchychant.com/ansible-pitfall-vars-variable/).

---

I am surprised by the behavior that you're seeing, but there are a couple of workarounds. First, here's a simple reproducer for the behavior, if you were inspired to open a bug report:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    inside_var: "hello world"
    intermediate_var: "{{ inside_var }}"
    outside_var: "intermediate_var"
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that:
          vars[outside_var] == lookup('vars', outside_var)
        fail_msg: >
          have "{{ vars[outside_var] }}", expected "{{ lookup('vars', outside_var) }}"
```

This outputs:

```json
TASK [assert] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "vars[outside_var] == lookup('vars', outside_var)",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "have \"{{ inside_var }}\", expected \"hello world\"\n"
}
```

And that shows you one of the workarounds; use `lookup('vars', ...)` instead of `vars[...]`. The other workaround is to use the `hostvars` object instead:

```yaml
hostvars[inventory_hostname][outside_var]
```

This won't work in the above example (because we're not creating hostvars), but would work just fine in your code (slightly modified to use a debug task rather than creating a file):

```yaml
- name: Debug var
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Replace dots with underscores in web_domain
      set_fact:
        cert_data_var_1: "vault_{{ web_domain.replace('.', '_') }}_cert_data"

    - name: Replace dots with underscores in web_domain
      set_fact:
        cert_data_var_2: "{{ web_domain.replace('.', '_') }}_cert_data"

    - name: Create Cert File /tmp/certfile.pem
      debug:
        msg:
          - some secret is {{ some_secret }}
          - cert data 1      = {{ cert_data_var_1 }}
          - vars cert data 1 = {{ vars[cert_data_var_1] }}
          - cert data 2      = {{ cert_data_var_2 }}
          - vars cert data 2 = {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][cert_data_var_2] }}
```

Which produces as output:

```json
TASK [Create Cert File /tmp/certfile.pem] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [node0] => {
    "msg": [
        "some secret is secret-code",
        "cert data 1      = vault_foo_example_com_cert_data",
        "vars cert data 1 = cert data for foo.example.com\n",
        "cert data 2      = foo_example_com_cert_data",
        "vars cert data 2 = cert data for foo.example.com\n"
    ]
}
ok: [node1] => {
    "msg": [
        "some secret is secret-code",
        "cert data 1      = vault_bar_example_com_cert_data",
        "vars cert data 1 = cert data for foo.example.com\n",
        "cert data 2      = bar_example_com_cert_data",
        "vars cert data 2 = cert data for foo.example.com\n"
    ]
}
```

For this test, `group_vars/all/global_vault.yaml` contains (encrypted):

```yaml
vault_some_secret: secret-code
vault_foo_example_com_cert_data: |
  cert data for foo.example.com
vault_bar_example_com_cert_data: |
  cert data for foo.example.com
```

`group_vars/all/global_vars.yaml` contains:

```yaml
some_secret: "{{ vault_some_secret }}"
foo_example_com_cert_data: "{{ vault_foo_example_com_cert_data }}"
bar_example_com_cert_data: "{{ vault_bar_example_com_cert_data }}"
```

And my inventory contains:

```yaml
all:
  vars:
    ansible_host: localhost
  hosts:
    node0:
      web_domain: foo.example.com
    node1:
      web_domain: bar.example.com
```

Comment: Thanks @larsks! Using `          {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][cert_data_var_2] }}` works great! I also found that this works: `{{ lookup('vars', cert_data_var_2)}}` also.

Comment: @RedCricket using the dictionary `vars` is a bad practice and you should try to stay away from it, see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/74904#issuecomment-854137949.

Comment: ...or the link at the very top of this answer :)

Comment: gptchat told me to do it. :)